# Centrifugal potential and gradient

Tags: forces, potential-energy, coordinate-systems, differentiation, textbook-erratum

I'm learning about angular moment and central forces, and in my syllabus I came across this formula:

[image]

How did they get 1 over r? I am familiar with the gradient, but I've never seen the gradient calculated for a central potential, so I think I'm a little bit confused here. I would have just thought that the magnitude of $F$ equals $-d(Uc)/dr$, but apparently a factor $1/r$ comes into play, and I don't know why.

Could someone help me?

Comment: It's a [typo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Del_formula). The author probably meant to write $\frac{\vec{\bf r}}{r}=\hat{\bf r}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In spherical coordinates, Gradient is calculated like that. It's derived from definition. And it's different from gradient in Cartesian coordinates. That's all.

[See here](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic970148.files/Spherical_coord.pdf)

If you want the reason, David J.Griffith says:

[image: why]

Also,

[image: table]